# I am installing "material-ui-icons" using command npm i -S material-ui-icons but getting error as follow

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

> npm WARN material-ui-search-bar@0.4.1 requires a peer of material-ui@<1.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>   npm WARN material-ui-search-bar@0.4.1 requires a peer of react@^15.5.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>   npm WARN material-ui-icons@1.0.0-beta.17 requires a peer of material-ui@^1.0.0-beta.16 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.2 (node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents):
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/home/alokkumar/my-app/node_modules/.staging/fsevents-d3f3daa6/node_modules/ajv' -> '/home/alokkumar/my-app/node_modules/.staging/ajv-2efe4df7' . 
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules/fsevents):
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/home/alokkumar/my-app/node_modules/.staging/fsevents-9912eb8e/node_modules/ajv' -> '/home/alokkumar/my-app/node_modules/.staging/ajv-4e89f7bf'
>
> npm ERR! path /home/alokkumar/my-app/node_modules/change-emitter
>   npm ERR! code ENOENT
>   npm ERR! errno -2
>   npm ERR! syscall rename
>   npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename  '/home/alokkumar/my-app/node_modules/change-emitter' ->  '/home/alokkumar/my-app/node_modules/.change-emitter.DELETE'
>   npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>   npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     /home/alokkumar/.npm/_logs/2018-01-05T17_27_55_766Z-debug.log

Comment: Can you try running with sudo? `sudo npm i -S`

Comment: A title should summarize your question, it should not be the question itself. Please edit your question to give it a better title, and add your real question to the body of the question.

Comment: Do you want to use the beta version of material-ui  (1.0.0-beta26)or the release version (0.X.X) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is self explanatory if read carefully.

'...requires a peer of material-ui@<1.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.'

Use this command first: `npm i -S material-ui`